# Unable to deploy a war org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener

Tags: deployment, jboss

While i am delpoying into jboss getting 
org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener exception

Comment: Line break on first page is nice so i just read "Unable to deploy a war"... made me think...

Comment: @Ajay99: Sorry, I left my crystal ball at home today. Do you really expect us to diagnose your problem from that description?

Answer (score 0):

comment out the following lines from the jbossweb.deployer/conf/web.xml:

`org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener 
com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener`

JARs being included in our application are the Sun RI JSF and EL JARs:

jsf-impl-1.1_02.jar 
jsf-api-1.1_02.jar 
el-api-1.0.jar 
el-ri-1.0.jar

Tell me if this helps.

~ Bharat

HCL Technologies